# iOS Objective-C Xcode - How to start to play video in Landscape only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm building a App to play 360 videos - all is working great !

However, I would like like the video to start to play only if the mobile is oriented in Landscape ! IF in portrait it should display a message "Please put your mobile in landscape" and if so - start to play the video . ..

Anybody have any idea how to achieve this ?

It would be amazing :)

Thanks !

---

EDIT:

my Viewcontroller.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  video360test
//
//  Created by linyize on 16/6/20.
//  Copyright © 2016年 islate. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

#import "Video360ViewController.h"

#import "CardboardViewController.h"
#import "CardboardSDK.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (IBAction)playURL:(id)sender
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://7b1gcw.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/demo1.mp4"];
Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil ];

}
}

- (IBAction)playFileffpvr:(id)sender
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];


[videoController VRMode:true];

if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (IBAction)playFileff360:(id)sender
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (IBAction)playFile2:(id)sender
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boa" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (IBAction)playFileffp:(id)sender
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boa" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

@end

@implementation LandscapeNavController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

the button displaying correctly the alert now:

```
- (IBAction)playFileffpvr:(id)sender

{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    [self doSomething];
else
    [self doSomethingElse];



Video360ViewController *videoController = [[Video360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTY360PlayerVC" bundle:nil url:url];

[videoController VRMode:true];

if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

and the alert being display:

```
-(void)doSomething
{

//Show Alert

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Simple" message:@"Turn your device to Landscape." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSLog(@"Cancel");
}];
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated: YES completion: nil];
}

-(void)doSomethingElse
{
//Function Body
//play the file
}
```

Comment: Are you using MPMoviePlayerController to play the videos??

Comment: Thanks to reply,

No, I am using https://github.com/islate/SlateVideo360

But if you have something working with MPMovie, I maybe able to make it work with that one ?

Comment: If you are presenting the Video View Controller, you can force it to be Landscape only....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need to do is create an `UINavigationController` subclass say `LandscapeNavController` and put the code below

**LandscapeNavController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LandscapeNavController : UINavigationController

@end
```

**LandscapeNavController.m**

```
@implementation LandscapeNavController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Now present the video controller as modal like mentioned below

```
VideoController *controller=<INITIALIZE>
LandscapeNavController *nav=[[LandscapeNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and make sure your rotation settings should be

[image]

Additionally in **AppDelegate.h** define

@property(assign) BOOL shouldRotate;

The above property should be set to **`YES`** before you present **VideoController** and **`NO`** before dismissing the **VideoController**.

And add the following code in **`AppDelegate.m`**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    if (shouldRotate)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**Note - The above code not tested right now, if you face problem ping.**

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property for `UIAlertController` as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)UIAlertController *alertController;
```

You can Use a code like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)deviceOrientationDidChange
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
         [self doSomething];
        else
             [self doSomethingElse];
    }
-(void)doSomething
{

//Show Alert

self.alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Simple" message:@"Turn your device to Landscape." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
    }];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        NSLog(@"OK");
    }];

    [self.alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [self.alertController addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
-(void)doSomethingElse
{
//Hide the AlertViewController
[self.alertController removeFromSuperview]; 
//Code to handle the playing of the file
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    return YES;
}
```

Happy Coding. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim,

I added that in my Viewcontroller.m without sucess, it just start the video to play in portrait . . ..  I have updated my original questoin with the code in my Viewcontroller.m if it helps ??

Thanks a lot for your time !!

Comment: ok, the message appear when I come into the view controller yes :)
But anyway that it appear only one I ve clicked to one of the button :( ?
And make it disappear once I an in ladnscape ?

It should take the following path:

When I arrive to my view controller, I click to one button. This button start to play a video.  on click of this button, if the user is in portrait, it should display this message, and make start the video only when the user is on landscape. 

Thanks for all your time ;)

Comment: Hm, Im having an error in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if I add a ';' after animated it asking for an expected identifier ??

Comment: Ok,

Now On press of my button, if it's in portrait, Ihave the alert being display.

If On Landscape, it start the Video. That's great.

My question is: is there a way to = when the alter is display - the user rotate the phone in landscape ( while the alter is ON) and then - when mobile is in landscape , the video start. because at the moment, I need to close the alert , rotate the phone, and click again the button to start.

Thanks a lot :) ( I have updated the code)

Comment: After : put Yes

Comment: Sorry i'm not sur to understand, after waht should I put Yes ?

Comment: after animated in  
Hm, Im having an error in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { if I add a ';' after animated it asking for an expected identifie

Comment: Hi Sorry, but It doesnt seem to work  on my side, when added a ';' after animated, i have still this error you just mention :( how to fix it ? any possibility to have a chat with you :) ?

Comment: After ':' put Yes like this animated:YES

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128248/discussion-between-tibewww-and-md-ibrahim-hassan).